# How to get jest-sonar-reporter to generate test-report.xml file within coverage folder

Tags: jestjs, sonarqube

The project is set up in the following way:

```
src
  folder1
    coverage folder      <- not being generated in this folder
    other files
    test-report.xml      <- being generated here
  folder2
    coverage folder
    other folders & files
  folder3
    coverage folder
    other folders & files
```

and so on. The coverage folder is generated when I run tests. The issue I'm running into is the test-report.xml file is being generated within folder1/2/3/etc.. but not within the coverage folder within those folders.

The package.json file looks like this:

```
"jestSonar": {
  "reportPath": "src/*/coverage",
  "reportFile": "test-report.xml",
  "indent": 4
}

"devDependencies": {

"jest-sonar-reporter": "2.0.0",

}
```

The jest-config.json file looks like this:

```
{
  "collectCoverage": true,
  "coverageDirectory": "coverage",
  "coverageReporters": ["json", "lcov"],
  "coverageThreshold": {
    "src/": {
      "statements": 0,
      "branches": 0,
      "functions": 0,
      "lines": 0
    }
  },
  "roots": ["test/"],
  "testURL": "http://localhost/",
  "testEnvironment": "jsdom",
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.[t|j]sx?$": ["babel-jest", {"rootMode": "upward"}]
  },
  "verbose": false,
  "testResultsProcessor": "jest-sonar-reporter"
}
```

Is there some thing I need to add/change so that the test-report.xml file is generated within each coverage folder?

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue. It's not really possible without hacking the package itself and maintaining a copy because the path is hardcoded in to the files that generate it.

As a solution I forked the repo and have updated it to allow for pathing, absolute v. relative pathing, and a few other features that I have seen the community asking for.

If you use my package `@casualbot/jest-sonar-reporter` you can set the file name and the outputDirectory:

```
{
  ...,
  "jest": {
    "rootDir": ".",
    "testResultsProcessor": "@casualbot/jest-sonar-reporter"
  },
  "@casualbot/jest-sonar-reporter": {
    "suiteName": "jest tests",
    "outputDirectory": "coverage", <=== directory 
    "outputName": "jest-report.xml", <=== filename
    "uniqueOutputName": "false",
    "classNameTemplate": "{classname}-{title}",
    "titleTemplate": "{classname}-{title}",
    "ancestorSeparator": " › ",
    "usePathForSuiteName": "true",
    "relativePaths": "true"
  }
}
```

Full disclosure I am the developer of this package, I just wanted to solve the problem and give back.